# Problem with htaccess redirect with rewrite module

Tags: .htaccess, apache2

I have an old url at:
http://example.com/search/admin

I want to make it go to:
http://example.com/cgi-bin/admin

This is what I have so far, which could be completely wrong...

```
RewriteRule ^/search/admin$ https://example.com/cgi-bin/admin
```

The mod_rewrite is definitely on and working and I am using apache 2.2.

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is; what error are you getting? What is the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little correction to Benubird post:

```
RewriteRule ^search\/admin\/?$ cgi-bin/admin [L]
```

RewriteRules never start with a slash and the redirect can be without slash.

Answer (score 1):

the ^ character matches the start of a line ( or url in this case). Just a thought, but maybe your line should be:

```
RewriteRule ^/search/admin$ /cgi-bin/admin
```

Otherwise I suspect you'll either not be redirected, or be getting redirected to https://example.comhttps://example.com/cgi-bin/admin